# Captures the Parameter Values from a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to debug an error in one of the my procedure.  The problem was I needed the exact values passed.

I was looking to capture the values in a procedure in the catch block when an error occurred.  I can see how to get the parameters, but not a great way of getting the values.

Ultimately, I would like the see the parameters and values in a json-like out put.

**Update:**
I am really looking for an dynamic way of getting the values.  These are being executed by a Web API. I wanted to be able to reuse this code in any procedure and run it in the ctach block when there is an error.

Comment: *"I can see how to get the parameters, but not a great way of getting the values."* Huh? There's only one way to get the values, `@YourParameterName`.

Comment: How is the proc executed? Is it directly called from client code, or is it nested with another `EXEC`? If the former you can use XEvents `rpc_completed` event. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/310937/using-an-extended-event-to-track-a-single-stored-procedure

Comment: What we did was create a procedure that generated the below "code" for a specific procedure you passed as parameter. then you just copypaste that code into your try / catch. There's no dynamic way of accessing the parameters while you're in call i think.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to insert a little code into your procedure

**Example**

```
Declare @P1 int = 25
Declare @P2 varchar(25) = 'Some Value'

Declare @JSON varchar(max) = (
Select P1 = @P1
      ,P2 = @P2
 For JSON Path, Without_Array_Wrapper
)

-- Now you have an @JSON String of your Parameters 

-- Your Procedure
```

**Your JSON String**

```
{"P1":25,"P2":"Some Value"}
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture parameter values and their corresponding values in a procedure during an error, you can use dynamic SQL and the sp_executesql system stored procedure to generate a JSON-like output. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LogErrorWithParameters
(
    @error_message NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @proc_name NVARCHAR(255),
    @params NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = N'
        DECLARE @param_json NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @param_json = (
            SELECT ' + @params + '
            FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
        )

        INSERT INTO ErrorLog (ErrorMessage, ProcedureName, Parameters)
        VALUES (@error_message, @proc_name, @param_json)
    '

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@error_message NVARCHAR(MAX), @proc_name NVARCHAR(255)', @error_message, @proc_name
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- Handle the error here, you can log it or re-throw it if needed.
    END CATCH
END
```

Here's how this works:

1. Create a stored procedure LogErrorWithParameters that takes three
   parameters: @error_message for the error message, @proc_name for the
   procedure name, and @params for a string containing parameter names
   and values in a JSON-like format.
2. Inside the procedure, dynamically generate SQL code using the
   @params parameter. This code converts the JSON-like string into a
   JSON object and inserts it along with other error information into
   an ErrorLog table.
3. Use sp_executesql to execute the dynamic SQL within a BEGIN
   TRY...END TRY block. If an error occurs during execution, it will be
   caught in the BEGIN CATCH...END CATCH block, where you can handle it
   as needed.

You can call this stored procedure from your other procedures within a CATCH block to log the error along with parameter values in a JSON-like format.

Example usage:

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- Your code here
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX)
    -- Construct the @params string with parameter names and values in JSON-like format
    SET @params = '"param1": "' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @param1) + '", "param2": "' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @param2) + '"'
    EXEC LogErrorWithParameters ERROR_MESSAGE(), 'YourProcedureName', @params
    -- Handle the error or re-throw it if needed
END CATCH
```